# Splitting in Python says to me, "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, split

I have this function.

```
blocklist_data = unpack_blocklist_data()
hostnames = []
for entry in blocklist_data:
    if not entry.startswith('#'):
        hostname = entry.split()
        if len(hostname) == 1:
            hostnames.append(hostname[0])
        else: hostnames.append(hostname[1])
return hostnames
```

blacklist_data is just different txt files. Some have entries that look like;

```
0.0.0.0 site.domain.org
```

Other files have entries that look like;

```
site.domain.org
```

Those are the only two options.

I am getting error in regard to the else: line;

```
 else: hostnames.append(hostname[1])
                        ~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am just wanting to split when the entry looks like 0.0.0.0 site.domain.org - otherwise, don't split because there is no need.

Comment: You have probably empty lines in the file. Try `if not entry.startswith('#') and entry.strip() != '':`

Comment: Are you sure you can *only* have `0.0.0.0 site.domain.org` or `site.domain.org` ?

Comment: @Andrej Kesely - Bingo, that was it. I also realized I don't technically need [0] because if the len isn't 1, only the hostname would be there. But this helped me catch an error / bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you can also try to solve it in a single line via list comprehensions with:

```
hostnames = [x.split()[0] if len(x.split()) == 1 else x.split()[1] for x in blocklist_data if (len(x) > 0 and not x.startswith("#"))]
```

Based on the following example:

```
blocklist_data = ['','0.0.0.0 site.domain.org','site.domain.org','# 0.0.0.0 site.domain.org']
hostnames = [x.split()[0] if len(x.split()) == 1 else x.split()[1] for x in blocklist_data if (len(x) > 0 and not x.startswith("#"))]
```

We get:

```
['site.domain.org', 'site.domain.org']
```